# я пишу на андроиде и у меня проблема с нажатием на 2 кнопки, питон думает что я пытаюсь приблизить экран. подскажите как мне это исправить

Tags: python, android, tkinter, button

```
from tkinter import*

tk = Tk()

btn1 = Button(text="тест")
btn1.place(x=10, y=50)

btn1 = Button(text="тест")
btn1.place(x=200, y=50)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, нет, как минимум простой, возможности отключить это.

Comment: Как минимум, tkinter, да и tk, насколько я понимаю, не предлагают какого-то функционала для управления этим, или он не на виду ..